# Cannot redirect to any website - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

i'am beginning with jQuery and really need help. I have image with hover, which show two buttons - edit and delete. And after click on gallery-edit button i just need redirect to any website. But it doesnt have any effect. This is my code:

```
<ul class="thumbnails galler">
<li id="image-1" class="thumbnail">
    <a style="background:url({$basePath}/images/products/item1.jpg)" title="Sample Image 1" href="{$basePath}/images/products/item1.jpg"><img class="grayscale" src="{$basePath}/images/products/item1.jpg" alt="Sample Image 1"></a>
</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
//gallery controlls container animation
$('ul.galler li').hover(function(){
    $('img',this).fadeToggle(1000);
    $(this).find('.gallery-controls').remove();
    $(this).append('<div class="well gallery-controls">'+
        '<p><a href="http://www.somewebsite.com" class="gallery-edit btn"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a> <a href="#" class="gallery-delete btn"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></p>'+
        '</div>');
    $(this).find('.gallery-controls').stop().animate({
        'margin-top':'-1'
    },400,'easeInQuint');
});

//gallery edit
$('.thumbnails').on('click','.gallery-edit',function(e){
    $.get(this.href);
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need that click function at all. If it's an anchor, and it has a href so it should be, it will go to that href if you remove the jQuery function ?

Answer (score 4):

`$.get` does not redirect, it does an ajax request for the url provided. You should use `location.href = {url}` instead.

Comment: His gallery edit button is surrounded by an anchor tag... so what is the purpose of the click function and doing location.href? Why can't they just click the link?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Good point, the `return false;` after `$.get()` is preventing the `a` tag from doing it's default action. If he removed the click handler altogether it would do what he needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the href, you can use native javascript to do this instead.

```
window.location.href = //insert url here;
```

But the problem with your code is that you are trying to retrieve the href through the `this` keyword. The `this` keyword refers to the event, not the actual anchor element you're trying to reference. To get the link, you want to use `e.currentTarget.href` instead.

**EDIT**: For some stupid reason, I didn't notice you were also using `$.get`. That function is not useful for what you want. Just use the native properties provided by the Window object to redirect the browser, as I and at least one other poster has shown you above.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `this`. However, isn't `$(e.target).prop('href')` what hes after in this case? Perhaps your example is the eqvavivalent using the native javascript dom api?

Comment: Yeah, you can use `$(e.target).prop('href')`. I'm always more of a fan of using native JavaScript though, as nothing's more efficient than native code.

Comment: Couldn't agree more. Especially since javascript will block the UI when running slow, its important to take performance in to consideration.